# Проблема с пост-запросом/ Angular5

Tags: javascript, angular5

Есть сервис с пост-запросом:

```
postData(data: any) {
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080', data);
}
```

Регистрирую его в компоненте. Хочу им воспользоваться. Передаю его в метод:

```
sendCsvFile() {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('csv-file', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
  this.http.postData(formData, {
    reportProgress: true,
    observe: 'events'
  })...
```

Но не могу, выдает такую ошибку:

> error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.

Comment: почему `postData` вызывается через `this.http`?

Comment: Извини, не написал. constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Описанный метод принимает всего один параметр:

```
postData(data: any) {
```

с названием `data`.

При вызове: `this.http.postData(formData, {...})` идет попытка передать **2** параметра.

Следовательно нужно либо изменить сигнатуру метода, либо передавать только один параметр.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Направили в нужное русло. Тупая тупость)))) с моей стороны.